# Proper use of c# razor Checkbox with Model in WebApp

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, checkbox, web-applications

I have problems creating a well working Checkbox in my c# WebApp.
Could someone show me a working version with a model and also how the View and the controller looks like.

Model:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TEST.Models
{
    public class Checkbox
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBox()
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TEST.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code and indicate what is not working

Comment: @Html.CheckBox("check", true, new {id = dir }), that is what I am trying right now, without model

Comment: You need a model with a `boolean` property - say `bool IsSelected` and then in the view use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)`, and when you post your form, the value of `IsSelected` will be either `true` of `false` based on the checked state of the checkbox

Comment: I try to contact my controller and have issues with it.
What parameter do I have to give him?
example:

public AvtionResult IsChecked (???) { if (??? = true) { } }

Comment: Show your code. We are not psychic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it will work.

Model:

```
namespace TEST.Models
{
    public class Checkbox
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Checkbox model)
    {
        // work with model.IsChecked
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model TEST.Models.Checkbox 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)
}
```

Comment: I always get an error in the first line of the view. @model **Checkbox** is marked wrong. The type or namespace 'Checkbox' could not be found. Unexpected use of an unbound generic name. Do you know how to correct this ?

Comment: Yes. change to @model TEST.Models.Checkbox - just add full namespace name of the class. Edited my post.

Comment: @IlbienP _"The type or namespace 'Checkbox' could not be found. Unexpected use of an unbound generic name"_ - do you have a generic Checkbox type in your application? Did you use the full namespace in your `@model` declaration?

Comment: It gives him the "generic" error, because Views are Generic C# classes and the model cannot be found. With the full namespace it should work correctly.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)